# SQL query not returning anything

Tags: mysql

How do I link across and get the variables of three tables, I want to get the linked facilities for each room but currently my record seems to be returning nothing.

I would like to return a new column header for facilities as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d6ca/25

The fiddle can be found here

```
SELECT *
FROM ts_room rm
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM ts_roompref rp
JOIN ts_request rq ON rp.request_id = rq.id AND day_id = 1 AND period_id = 1
WHERE rm.id = rp.room_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM ts_roompref rp
JOIN ts_allocation a ON rp.request_id = a.request_id AND a.status = "Allocated" 
WHERE rm.id = rp.room_id)
AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM ts_roomfacilities f
JOIN ts_room b ON f.room_id = b.id 
WHERE rm.id = f.room_id AND 
f.facilities_id=2);
AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM ts_facilities f1
JOIN ts_roomfacilities c ON f2.id = c.id 
WHERE rm.id = f.room_id);
```

Comment: closing as too localized.

Comment: There is also a typo in the 2nd line from the end I think. `JOIN ts_roomfacilities c ON f2.id = c.id` should be `JOIN ts_roomfacilities c ON f1.id = c.id`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a ; in the middle of your query which you should remove